# Simple database insert module

Tags: button, input, insert, admin, magento-1.7

So iv been playing with magento for a few months now, i really though i was getting the hang of it until i ventured into trying to write my own module. Iv started simple, all i am trying to achieve is to get a input box and a button within an admin page of the backend of magento.

I've spent the last 2 days putting together a basic admin module from many different tutorials. I have successfully set up a module that appears in the backend, and it shows both an input field and a button.

Within my `indexController` I have the following code

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('presbo/view'));

    $this->renderLayout();


}   
public function testAction()
{

    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
    ->getConnection('core_write');

    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $fields = array();
    $fields['name']= 'andy';
    $connection->insert('test', $fields);


    $fields = array();
    $fields['name']= 'andy2';
    $connection->insert('test',$fields);

    $connection->commit();
}
```

then within the view file i have the following

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $html="hello world <input type='text' /><input type='button' value='save' />";

    return $html;
}
```

so this all works fine the block is loaded an displayed within the backend.

Now I don't want to be given an answer (to be honest I doubt anyone will give an answer) but I don't even know where to start with searching for linking this button to the `testAction` within the controller. Basically I want the user to be able to input a number into the textfield and then when they press a button it will save it to the database table specified.

If I put the code that is in the `testAction`, within the `indexAction`and visit the page an entry is successfully inserted into the database table. but I need the user to be able to specify values.

Am I going about this totally the wrong way?

Comment: @Martijn erm why would you go through highlighting things and remove my "thank you message?"

Comment: See the [FAQ#editing]; posts are collaboratively edited and improved. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) for why I removed the "thank you" item at the end of the post.